# Função Javascript com Class

Tags: javascript, classes, animação

Boas,

Tenho o seguinte código que corre uma sequência de imagens:

```
 var setInter = null
 function startAnimation() {
     var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
     var frameCount = frames.length;
     var i = 0;
     setInter = setInterval(function () {
         frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
         frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
         if(i>=18){ 
             clearInterval(setInter);
         }
     }, 100);
 }
```

Isto corre uma animação por frames, e quando a condição acontece, ou seja 19 frames, a animação pára.

Eu quero que a animação aconteça quando o div #animation tenha a class "in-view". Esta parte já está tratada, e quando faço scroll até à div, a mesma ganha a class "in-view", contudo não arranjo forma da função ativar e a animação acontecer.

Soluções sem ser por JQuery.

Obrigado!

Comment: Como está o código que adiciona a class `in-view`? Teria como colocar ele em sua pergunta?

Comment: Quando vc faz scroll até a div, não tem como chamar a função `startAnimation()`?